# CSS - Grouping Selectors AND pseudo classes

Tags: css, syntax, grouping, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a bunch of selectors i'm wanting to group, which is easily done this way:

```
.class1 #id1, .class2 #id2, .class3 #id3 { }
```

And I also want to apply psuedo classes on them.

But is there a way to group multiple selectors, AND multiple pseudo classes without repeating myself?

ie. I would like all the above elements, in either Link, Hover and Active states to have the same styling.
Do I have to do it like this?

```
.class1 #id1:link, .class2 #id2:link, .class3 #id3:link, .class1 #id1:hover, .class2 #id2:hover, .class3 #id3:hover, .class1 #id1:active, .class2 #id2:active, .class3 #id3:active {}
```

or is there a better way?

EDIT:

I'd like to clarify my position.
I have a list of links arranged something like this:

```
<div class="NAV">
 <a id="id1"></div>
 <a id="id2"></div>
 <a id="id3"></div>
 <a id="id4"></div>
</div>
```

but class `NAV`, is actually an interchangeable class name using `<?php echo $current ?>`

So my CSS reflects a scenario where NAV is either `class1`, `class2`, `class3` OR `class4` & one of the ids listed above are parent and child. eg. `class1 > id1`

So to create one style to reflect all scenarios I have to represent ALL scenarios and group them. I was hoping there was a way to at least group the pseudo classes separately so I don't have to create 3 times the amount of elements for each link state.

Comment: Since your element ids should be unique, there's no reason to include the parent class in the selector. If .class1 #id1 selects a different element than just #id1, you've done something wrong. That by itself shortens your selector quite a bit.

Comment: That would normally be relevant, but I'm using it as a condition, since the parent changes its class name (using php), and so I don't want the style to apply when it doesn't match that specific parent class. U follow?

Answer (score 1):

As a general answer: Yes, you have to do this. There's no better way. because your elements have different parents.

But consider the markup below:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div id="id1">
        <div class="some-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <div class="some-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="id3">
        <div class="some-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case you can select the elements like this:

```
.class1 > div:hover {
    // your css rule...
}
```

And not effect `div`'s with class `some-div`

Comment: Yeap, my bad. @MrLister

Answer (score 0):

You can give the affected elements a unique class of their own.

```
<div class="class1">
   <a id="id1" class="hoverable">xxx</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
   <a id="id3" class="hoverable">xxx</a>
</div>
<div class="class3">
   <a id="id3" class="hoverable">xxx</a>
</div>
```

Then all you need for the CSS is

```
.hoverable:link, .hoverable:hover, .hoverable:active {}
```